# Git: Update local branch from master without changing locally changed files

Tags: git

My company recently switched from SVN to Git, so there's no real internal knowledge-base: we're trying to wrap our heads around the terminology and process of Git.

The use case is when I want to update my local branch with the latest changes from master, however I want any files I have changed on my local to "trump" any changes from master.

Basically, How do I update my local with latest changes without losing my work?

Comment: Are your local changes committed?

Comment: As far as a local knowledge base, you might find this page by Atlassian handy: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-fetch, which talks about git from an SVN perspective.

Comment: @TimCastelijns The local changes are committed to my local branch, I want to make sure the rest of the project is up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git checkout local_branch
```

`git add` and
`git commit`
 your local changes, then, while still in that branch

```
git fetch master        # get the latest master into origin
git merge -xours origin/master # and merge it in
```

You may also find http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging useful.

Comment: This will work but would remove any local changes. You may want to use `git stash` to preserve those changes.

Comment: Also, if you plan to do `git fetch` and `git merge` in sequence, you may want to consider `git pull` instead.

Comment: This answer helped- I was using fetch, but not doing the merge. It also helps to know that git pull == git fetch; git merge. Also I didn't know about the our/theirs/xours modifiers. That can come in handy. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

git will not allow you to pull anything from master if you have made changes that haven't been commited. So run a `git stash` and then you can safely run a `git pull`. Then you can run `git stash pop` to put your changes back in. If git cannot figure it out, it will warn you.